# Get server exception to display on error page ASP.NET Razor pages

Tags: asp.net, exception, backend, razor-pages

I have a redirect page whenever an error occurs named error.cshtml but I am not sure how to access server errors to be displayed on this page for remote trouble shooting. I know it bad practice to display such info but its only temporary. Any ideas?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC? Post your existing cshtml and related controller code?

Comment: I'm not using MVC, razor pages rather

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To whomever this may concern, if like me you wish to view server sided errors on a deployed razor page application, you can add `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()` in your `Configure` method of the `Startup.cs` file. This is enabled by default if you are running in dev mode. Be warned however; this will display all exceptions that occur on your website to anyone.